# Distinction between passing i and &i to a function

Tags: objective-c, c

What is the difference between the following pairs of statments?

```
   int i;
   doSomethingWith(i);
```

and

```
   int i;
   doSomethingWith(&i);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the & is the address-of operator. So instead of passing a copy of `i` like you do in the first call, you pass the address of `i`, or `&i`, which means the function can modify it directly.

The function will look like this:

```
void doSomethingWith (int *var);
```

This means it takes a pointer (something that holds the address) to an integer (in this case, `i`). Then, to modify `i` directly, the function can do:

```
*var = 5;
```

This is the dereferencing operator, which gives you what is actually stored at that address. This call will assign 5 to what is stored at the memory location you pass with &i.

Any C textbook should explain this in great detail when it talks about pointers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.  That's kind of what I thought.

Comment: So by using that dereferencing operator, you're getting the value of that memory location thus saving a little memory (the amount of bytes the integer takes)?

Comment: The dereferencing operator pulls up what's stored at the memory location you give it. A pointer holds a memory location. If you were to output `var`, you'd see something like 0x22ff44: the address it's holding. `*var = 5` stores a 5 *in* 0x22ff44 (or whatever the address of i was), so `i` will equal 5.

Comment: There will still be memory used for the integer `i` and the pointer `var` (for the life of the function).

Answer (score 2):

In the first you're passing the value of i. In the second you're passing the address, in memory, of the variable i.

Have a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnXkiAKbUPg) video about pointers and that kind of stuff.

Comment: @KenThomases Binky was actually linked in one of my classes, Operating Systems I think. Great video.

Answer (score 0):

- Passing 'i' --> pass the value of i (value inside the memory location)
- Passing '&i' --> pass a reference to the memory location of 'i'